Visual Studio 2010 crashes on startup (splash screen)
I'm using Windows 10. My Visual Studio 2010 will no longer start. I've tried repair, /safemode and deleting the folder %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0
The Event Viewer shows the following:


I know VS2010 is really old but I would like to get it going again. My PC may have done a Windows 10 update that's somehow broken it.
Any ideas?
I have the exact same version of Windows 10 on my desktop PC. The versions of kernelbase.dll are also identical in both System32 and SysWow64 folders.
I tried sfc /scannow and rebooted - no difference.
Booted into Windows Safe Mode - no difference.

I can guarantee you that Windows 10 didn't update to break Visual Studio.  There is something else going on. Just to confirm. Visual Studio does not open at all, simply crashes, in other words you have no ability to open any solution(s). This has solutions you have not attempted.

@Ramhound that is correct. I see the splash screen, that disappears quietly - not even a dialog box saying that its crashed and that's that.
I can't get the program to start, so no chance of opening or creating any solutions at all. At least I have 2 machines I can compare against.

@Ramhound I have attempted other solutions on that link - with the exception of replacing my SSD.
